# Map Reduce String out of bound error on String Concatenation

Tags: java, mapreduce

I am trying to write a map reduce code that takes a table stored in text file. The table has two attributes. One is id and second is name and the code should take all the values with same id and concatenate them . Ex: 1 xyz 2 xyz 1 abc should result to 1 xyzabc 2 xyz. 
Following is my version of code.As a beginner i have modified the MaxTemperature code to learn doing that

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class MaxTemperature {

public static class MaxTemperatureMapper
  extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

  @Override
  public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context)
  throws IOException, InterruptedException {

   String line = value.toString();
   String lastWord = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
    Text valq = new Text();
   valq.set(line.substring(0,4));
     context.write(new Text(lastWord), valq );
      }
   }

public static class MaxTemperatureReducer
 extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

  @Override
  public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
     Context context)
     throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String p="";
  for (Text value : values) {
  p=p+value.toString();
   }
Text aa= new Text();
aa.set(p);  
context.write(key, new Text(aa));
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   if (args.length != 2) {
     System.err.println("Usage: MaxTemperature <input path> <output path>");
     System.exit(-1);
   }

    Job job = new Job();
    job.setJarByClass(MaxTemperature.class);
    job.setJobName("Max temperature");

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

job.setMapperClass(MaxTemperatureMapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(MaxTemperatureReducer.class);

job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
   job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

My input file

```
123456 name
123456 name
123456 age
123456 age
123456 relation
132323 age
123565 name
258963 test
258963 age
254789 age
254259 age
652145 name
985745 name
523698 name
214569 ame
123546 name
123456 age
321456 age
123456 age
124589 hyderabad
```

~
Expected Output

```
123456 name,name,age (all values with index 123456)
124589 hyderabad (al values with index 124589)
```

I got the following error

```
  java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1907)
    at MaxTemperature$MaxTemperatureMapper.map(MaxTemperature.java:39)
    at MaxTemperature$MaxTemperatureMapper.map(MaxTemperature.java:26)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
```

Comment: For `substring()` doc says `IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.`. Make sure end-index 4 is enough.

Comment: Yeah i took it like 15456654 ie a huge number still its showing the same

Answer (score 0):

3 things:

1. You haven't described the expected input very well, especially in the context of your code.
2. You haven't described what you're trying to do with your map/reduce methods, even if I can understand what you're trying to do.
3. You should check out the Javadoc for String.substring(int, int): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int, int)